# Populate Flot chart with text from div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, flot

I'm trying to populate a Flot chart with data from a MySQL query in PHP. I'm sure this is a crappy way to go about things (without Ajax or JSON, neither of which I'm comfortable with yet), but I output the query results in the format Flot needs for its data points into a hidden div on my PHP page, like so:

```
function get_team_chart($arr) {
    $data1 = array();
    $data2 = array();
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $data1[] = '[' . $a['week'] . ',' . $a['pts'] . ']';
        $data2[] = '[' . $a['week'] . ',' . $a['league_avg'] . ']';
    }
    $str1 = implode(', ', $data1);
    $str2 = implode(', ', $data2);
    echo "  <div id='series1' style='display:none;'>" . $str1 . "</div>
            <div id='series2' style='display:none;'>" . $str2 . "</div>";           
}
```

Then I try to pull that data into my chart in JavaScript like so:

```
function plot_team_chart() {
    var series1 = $('#series1').html();
    var series2 = $('#series2').html();
    $.plot( $("#team-chart"),
            [   series1,
                series2],
            {   xaxis: {min:0,
                        max:13},
                yaxis: {max:150,
                        min:0}}
    );
```

}

This doesn't throw any JS errors at runtime, and the chart shows up with the specified mins and maxes, but no data is plotted. I checked the values of `series1` and `series2` and they are both without quotes around the numerical values (i.e. they are like `[1,120.3], [2,89.0]`, not like `["1","120.3"], ["2","89.0"]`).

This is my first foray into the world of Flot, so please be gentle. Also, I verified that the chart plots fine with hardcoded values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Feel free to respond with how this functionality would be accomplished with Ajax and/or JSON, but here is how I accomplished pulling in data within a hidden div to plot on Flot:

```
function plot_team_chart() {
    var tmp1 = new Array();
    var tmp2 = new Array();
    var tmp3 = new Array();
    var data = new Array();
    $('.to-plot').each(function() {
        tmp1 = $(this).html().split('|');
        for (var i=0; i<tmp1.length; i++) {
            tmp2 = tmp1[i].split(',');
            tmp3.push(tmp2);
        }
        data.push({ label: $(this).attr('data_label'),
                    data: tmp3});
        tmp3 = [];
    });

    var options = { xaxis: {    min:1,
                                max:13},
                    yaxis: {    max:120,
                                min:30},
                    grid: {     borderColor:'#ccc'},
                    legend: {   show:true,
                                position:'se'}};

    if (data.length > 0) {
        $.plot( $("#team-chart"),
                data,
                options
        );
    }
}
```

And the modified PHP to accommodate the changes:

```
function get_team_chart($arr) {
    $data1 = array();
    $data2 = array();
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $data1[] = $a["week"] . "," . $a["pts"];
        $data2[] = $a["week"] . "," . $a["league_avg"];
    }
    $str1 = implode('|', $data1);
    $str2 = implode('|', $data2);
    echo "  <div id='series1' data_label='avg score' style='display:none;'>" . $str1 . "</div>
            <div id='series2' data_label='league avg' style='display:none;'>" . $str2 . "</div>";           
}
```

Comment: OK, now can anyone tell me how to add labels to my series within the JS code above? I set an attribute in the divs, `data_label`, that stores the value of the label I want to set (code above updated).

Comment: Got the labels working too! (Code for `push()` updated above to reflect.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want quotes around those variables, why not do:

```
$data1[] = '["' . $a['week'] . '","' . $a['pts'] . '"]';
$data2[] = '["' . $a['week'] . '","' . $a['league_avg'] . '"]';
```

That will quote your output via the lazy man's way.

Comment: I don't think I _want_ quotes around the variables; I believe the output I'm seeing (without quotes) is the correct format for Flot. That's why I'm confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: My next guess would be Flot, I've never used it so I'm not sure, doesn't want strings. It wants the variable types to actually be set as integers or decimals. Did you even try quoting your results to see if it would plot?

Comment: I tried adding quotes, same result. Is there a way I can cast the numerical values as numbers in Javascript? Would I have to use regex matching to find the actual numbers within the string at that point?